mocking commandline arguments
In my code I am using Environment.GetCommandLineargs
How could I mock the Command Line Arguments to mock the command line options.
public interface ICommandLineInterface { string[] GetCommandLineArgs(); }
public class CommandInterface : ICommandLineInterface {
  public string[] GetCommandLineArgs() {
    return Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
  }
}
 [Fact]
public void Test1() {
  string[] expectedArgs = new[]{"Hello", "World", "Fake", "Args"};
  var mockedCLI = new Mock<ICommandLineInterface>();
  mockedCLI.Setup(m => m.GetCommandLineArgs()).Returns(expectedArgs);

  var result = empLib.Instance.Initialize(false);
}

public class empLib {
  private static empLib mInstance = null;
  public static empLib Instance {
    get {
      if (null == mInstance) {
        mInstance = new empLib();
      }
      return mInstance;
    }
  }
  public bool Initialize(bool isWindowsService) {
    CommandLineOptions cmd = new CommandLineOptions();
    cmd.PopulateFromCommandLineArgs(false);
    // code manupulations with args
    return true;
  }
}

public class CommandLineOptions {
  public void PopulateFromCommandLineArgs(bool isWindowsService) {
    // How to mock below line of code
    string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", args));
  }
}

When I try to debug the Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(), I am not getting the mocked data.
What would be the right solution to it.

You cannot mock the Environment (at least not to my knowledge). So your class empLib uses a class called CommandLineOptions which directly uses Environment. Somewhere in this chain, you need to use some kind of dependency injection, to replace the call to Environment to a call to some implementation of ICommandLineInterface.

The most simple way is to change the code tested and wrap Environment.GetCommandLineArgs into some interface like e.g. ICommandLineArgProvider that has a method: string[] GetCommandLineArgs(); Inject that dependency into the type tested. Then you can mock ICommandLineArgProvider super easily.

I see the isWindowsService argument in one of your methods so I'll make an assumption with this answer that we are dealing with a Windows Service project here.
Mocking Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() would likely only work when using a very low level assembly replacement library such as Microsoft Fakes, which does allow you to mock static classes and methods. However, I would not recommend going down that route as those libraries are not trivial to use and have harsh requirements (for instance, Microsoft Fakes is only usable with Visual Studio Enterprise).
Instead, I suggest moving away from that dependency altogether.
For a Windows Service project, my suggestion would be to switch into a "worker" project template and use the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices NuGet package to allow hosting the project as a native Windows Service. This is a more modern hosting model for this type of project so it would be a recommendation regardless if it solved your issue or not.
Then, as you now have a proper hosting environment, command line arguments are automatically handled by the host and converted into IConfiguration settings. This now means you have a ton of options as IConfiguration is an interface you can either inject directly into your classes to read the arguments, like:
public class SomeService(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    public void Method()
    {
        var someCmdLine = configuration.GetValue<bool>("SomeCmdLineKey");
        ...
    }
}

Then, in this case, it would be a matter of mocking IConfiguration itself to return whatever you wanted for each of your cmdline arguments and you'd be set.
If you don't want to completely rework your project (assuming you are not using the hosting model yet), you could still tap into this same mechanism by directly configuring the cmdline args configuration provider like this in your code:
IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddCommandLine(args)
    .Build();

Then you can just pass that config object around to whoever needs to read the command line arguments. All this needs is a dependency on Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine
But you can do even better if you consider leveraging System.CommandLine which would give you a strongly typed way of reading and handling command line arguments. This would be my recommendation if you want to have your application be more robust and maintainable.
TL;DR would be to always avoid directly handling command line arguments unless your application is extremely simple.
